# How to calculate a percentage for all student that are present

Tags: php, mysql

There are two tables that are going to work together.

1st Table:

```
AttendanceID TeacherID BatchID SubjectID SemesterID Date 
          32       110       8         9          1 2016-08-04 
          31       102       8        10          1 2016-07-17 
          30       108       6        22          3 2016-06-27 
          29       109       7        18          2 2016-06-27 
          28       109       8        13          1 2016-06-27 
          27       110       7         7          2 2016-06-27 
          26       110       8         9          1 2016-06-27 
          25       104       2        42          7 2016-04-20 
          24       104       5        35          5 2016-04-14 
          23       104       2        42          7 2016-04-14
          22       102       2        41          7 2016-04-13 
          21       102       2        41          7 2016-04-10 
          20       102       6        23          3 2016-04-10 
          19       102       6        23          3 2016-04-10
```

2nd Table:

[image]

The first table is consist of unique rows which will be going to use for each new attendance list in table two.

For example: In the first table, the `AttendanceID` `21` is used in second table for Complete attendance of specific subject.

I want to calculate the percentage of all students in second table of a specific `Subject` and the total number can be get by the 1st table `AttendanceID`

What I did in PHP is: First I get the total number from 1st table with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(AttendanceID) FROM attendances WHERE SubjectID = ? AND BatchID = ?"
```

Once I get the total number of attendances of specific subject and batch from first table I store it in variable `$total` then I write another query for getting obtained attendance from second table:

```
SELECT COUNT(AttendanceDetailID) FROM attendancedetail WHERE CollegeID = ? AND Status = 'present' AND SubjectID = ?"
```

After getting the obtained attendance I store it in variable `$obtained`
Once I get both values then I calculate the percentage in PHP like this:

```
    if(!empty($total) && !empty($obtained)) {
    $result = (($obtained * 100)/ $total);
        $result = round($result);
    }
```

Here is the complete code of PHP:

```
    public function showStateOfAttendance($subjectID, $batchID){

 $st = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT CollegeID, Name, Gender, Photo FROM students WHERE BatchID = ?");
    $st->bind_param("i", $batchID);
    $st->execute();
    $st->store_result();
    $num_rows = $st->num_rows;
    $st->bind_result($college_id, $name, $gender, $photo);


    $this->response['attendance'] = array();
    while($st->fetch()) {

        $this->calcultaionOfAttendance($subjectID, $college_id, $name,  $gender, $photo, $batchID);



    }
     return json_encode($this->response);
    $st->free_result();
    $st->close();

}


public function calcultaionOfAttendance($subjectID, $studentID, $name, $gender, $photo,  $batchID) {

      $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(AttendanceID) FROM attendances WHERE SubjectID = ? AND BatchID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ii", $subjectID, $batchID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->bind_result($AttendanceID);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
       $total = $AttendanceID;  
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();

    $stmt2 = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(AttendanceDetailID) FROM attendancedetail WHERE CollegeID = ? AND Status = 'present' AND SubjectID = ?");
    $stmt2->bind_param("ii", $studentID, $subjectID);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $stmt2->store_result();
    $stmt2->bind_result($AttendanceDetailID);
    while($stmt2->fetch()){
        $obtained = $AttendanceDetailID;
    }
    if(!empty($total) && !empty($obtained)) {
    $result = (($obtained * 100)/ $total);
        $result = round($result);
       $rating = ($result)/20;

         $tmp = array();

          $tmp['result'] = $result;
          $tmp['total'] = $total;
          $tmp['obtained'] = $obtained;
          $tmp['rating'] = $rating;
          $tmp['name'] = $name;
          $tmp['college_id'] = $studentID;
          $tmp['gender'] = $gender;
          $tmp['photo'] = $photo;

        array_push($this->response['attendance'],$tmp);



    //var_dump(array($total, $obtained, $result, $rating, $studentID, $name));
    }else if(empty($total)) {

         $tmp = array();

          $tmp['result'] = 0.0;
          $tmp['total'] = 0.0;
          $tmp['obtained'] = $obtained;
          $tmp['rating'] = 0.0;
          $tmp['name'] = $name;
          $tmp['college_id'] = $studentID;
        array_push($this->response['attendance'],$tmp);


    //var_dump(array("0.0",$obtained, "0.0","0.0",$studentID,$name));
    }else if(empty($obtained)) {

         $tmp = array();

          $tmp['result'] = 0.0;
          $tmp['total'] = $total;
          $tmp['obtained'] = 0.0;
          $tmp['rating'] = 0.0;
          $tmp['name'] = $name;
          $tmp['college_id'] = $studentID;
        array_push($this->response['attendance'],$tmp);


    //var_dump(array($total, "0.0", "0.0","0.0", $studentID , $name));
    }


}
```

Here is the android screen shot of the queries I did: The following result is for `SubjectID = 23` And `BatchID = 6`

[image]

It get me the required result but I need better way to calculate this, is it possible to do this with single query?

Thanks

Comment: fyi, a switch-a-roo on the function parameters name.  $this->calcultaionOfAttendance($subjectID, $college_id, $name,  $gender, $photo, $batchID); and public function calcultaionOfAttendance($subjectID, $studentID, $name, $gender, $photo,  $batchID) {

Comment: Sorry I don't understand can you elaborate more please

Comment: just tracing through your functions to attempt to see what its doing; you passed in $college_id but the calculationofAttendance is refering it as $studentID; it might add a little confusing but nothing biggy.

Comment: okay thank you sure I'll change it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    SELECT  s.CollectID, s.Name, s.Gender, s.Photo, 
        (SELECT count(AttendanceID) from attendances WHERE SubjectID =? and BatchID = s.BatchID) as total,
        (SELECT count(AttendanceDetailID) FROM attendancedetail WHERE CollegeID = s.CollectID and Status = 'present' and SubjectID = ?) as obtained
 FROM students s
 WHERE s.BatchID = ?
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks allot. Please suggest me the place where I can also learn these complex queries.

Comment: just have to be exposed to it and you will get good at it.  i write over a page long queries all the time at work hehe.  But if your code gets you the correct results, you just have to do some tracing and see what it is doing.

Comment: great. and you are amazing you guessed `students` table by yourself Amazing. I want to add you as friend on FB or anywhere because I need person like you in my college project for some queries. Pleaseeee

Comment: showStateOfAttendance() exposed the students table to me.

Comment: superb.. drop me mail by this `sharoonamjid@gmail.com` whenever I get any question related to queries I'll post it in Stack Overflow and send you the link of question to help me out. is it fine?

Comment: sure. for now, just keep up with what you are doing -- keeping the queries separate, then trace through and see what you passed in to each, then attempt to combine. You will eventually find yourself writing bigger queries after you get used to it.

Comment: gl, i sent an email with step-by-step break down to the final query that does what your queries are doing in the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

Put your queries in subselects:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(AttendanceDetailID) FROM attendancedetail WHERE CollegeID = ? AND Status = 'present' AND SubjectID = ?) 
/ (SELECT COUNT(AttendanceID) FROM attendances WHERE SubjectID = ? AND BatchID = ?)
* 100
```

Or (more readable) join two subqueries:

```
SELECT (obtained * 100) / total
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(AttendanceDetailID) AS total
    FROM attendancedetail
    WHERE CollegeID = ? AND Status = 'present' AND SubjectID = ?
) t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(AttendanceID) AS obtained 
    FROM attendances
    WHERE SubjectID = ? AND BatchID = ?
) a
```

Comment: its giving me this error in PhpMyAdmin Mysql:

Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: its showing just single row, not all students. Please show me some ways to get each student calculation of specific subject and batch keeping in mind the Count of `AttendanceID`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   SUM(`Status` = 'present') AS presentCount,
   COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
   (SUM(`Status` = 'present') * 100) / COUNT(*) AS percent  
FROM
   details    
WHERE
   BatchID = 2 
   AND SubjectID = 41 
   AND CollegeID = 1214    
GROUP BY
   AttendanceID
```

Based on your example you don't even need to access the first table. You can just calculate it directly from the data in the second.

Comment: Hi Its working great but it is giving me the calculation of only single student. How do I get calculation of each student of a specific batch and subject

Comment: remove `AND CollegeID = 1214 ` from the where clause I'd guess

Comment: I tried but it gives calculation of only this studentID: 1212 and the results are:

presentCount___totalCount___percent
17____________17________100
6______________17_______35


Its is only the result of this student:
1212 even I removed `AND CollegeID = 1214`

Comment: Then you need to show me the code with which you are calling this query. You can edit your question

Comment: I'm executing your query in PHPMyAdmin MySql

Comment: I like your query, it working perfect but need it for all student calculation

Comment: There is nothing in the query which would reduce it to only one student. Also I don't see a studentID in your sample data

Comment: My mistake, by studentID I mean CollegeID. I'm thinking same what you are thinking, you query seems to be perfect but don't know why its returning only 2 rows for batchID=2 and SubjectID = 41

Comment: Because it is grouping by AttendanceID and there are only 2 different AttendanceID's with batchID = 2 and SubjectID = 41.. but those were only examples anyway

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: No, just think about which criteria should be searched.

Comment: I'm updating the question and will also display the android screen shot which gets the result from the above queries which I did manually in PHP

Comment: This is getting a little messy. Is there still a problem? The query shows you the % of 'present' status for distinct attendanceIDs where subjectID = x and batchID = y. That is what you asked for in your question.

Comment: @Philipp I tried many ways to make you query somehow work for me but I'm not getting more than two rows for any subject for any batch. Please can you tell me some other way to achieve, I know you can do it.

Comment: Please provide some sample what result you would be expecting with the combination of batchID = 2 and subjectID = 41. Or some other combination, but I need something to see what result you want to have

Comment: As you can see in the above screen shot of android app, it's the result form `BatchID = 8` And `SubjectID = 16` As you can see all students are showing with these combination using long process of PHP, But I need it to make it your way in single query or may be some other short and perfect way.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Please use the data you provided to show me how the result should look like. My query filters your data by the subjectID and batchID and then groups the result by the attendanceID. Maybe you don't actually need the `WHERE` if you want to have all the students?

Comment: @Philipp I updated the above android screen shot. Its the output of this combination: `SubjectID = 23` And `BatchID = 6`

Comment: So that would be the correct result? And what result does my query give you when you use those ids?

Comment: Your query showing only two result of same student whose CollegeID is `6621`

Comment: Because there are only 2 different AttendanceIDs for those values. Though I don't know where you are even taking the CollegeID from as it doesn't get selected by my query. TBH, it doesn't make sense to keep this going, we are moving in circles.

Comment: Thank you for giving your time for my question. Your answer is helpful to make me understand more complex queries in future +1